# Virtual Box and TCP/IP

Tags: python, tcp, port

I want to connect with TCP/IP communication between virtual box and my own machine. My machine is ubuntu and virtual machine win8 
I created slave ubuntu side like this: TCP_IP address refer to  my win 8 ipv4  address

```
TCP_IP = '10.0.2.2'
TCP_PORT = 502
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
```

at the win 8 side, i am using Simply Modbus Tcp Program and i gave the that ip addres my ubuntu side's ethernet ip address ( i find with ifconfig)192.168.... but connection cant start.

I have this error my windows side:

```
    Error 63: occured at TCP Open Connection 
The network connection was refused by the server
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43517592/7026554

Comment: My suggest is using [ZMQ](https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) communication instead of pure socket.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error message, the server is either not listening on port 502, or there is a firewall rule that blocks that port.